# CURDATE gives error

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have an INSERT statement,

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO numbertable (numbers, numdate, salesperson, color) VALUES (?, NOW(), ?, ?)");
```

My SELECT statement looks like this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT FROM numbertable WHERE DATE(numdate) == CURDATE()");
```

When I run my select statement, I get the following error. Does anybody know what that could be?

```
SELECT COUNT FROM numbertable WHERE DATE(numdate) == CURDATE()
 LIMIT 0, 30 
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== CURDATE()
LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

Comment: `WHERE DATE(numdate) = CURDATE()`.  SQL doesn't have an `==` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mySQL you need `=` as equal sign, not `==`. should be:

```
SELECT COUNT FROM numbertable WHERE DATE(numdate) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, that solved the problem. I am a little confused, because when I run my code in PhpMyAdmin, I get returned that there was 6 affected rows today, which is true. When I run my code in my phppage Query, I get that there is 507 rows(That is all my rows in my database)

Comment: It is the exact same query:

SELECT * FROM numbertable WHERE DATE(numdate) = CURDATE()

When I use:

SELECT COUNT FROM numbertable WHERE DATE(numdate) = CURDATE()

I get the error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on boolean: 

Could you have an idea what that could be?

Comment: is count a column in your table? this is a reserved word, you should use select \`count\` if it is the case

Comment: Hello. No that is not a column in my database. It is really weird.

Comment: than what are you trying to do? count all results? if so it should be `count(*)`

Comment: You are a god. Thank you a lot :)